# Thumbnails won't show from specific server. Identical page's thumbs works from other server

Tags: facebook, web-scraping, thumbnails

I've placed two identical files on two different servers to test how the thumbnails work when sharing in FB. Other domain works, the other doesn't. FB debugger gives 503 and scraper says "Document returned no data".

Works:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.muikkumedia.fi%2Ffacebook%2F

Doesn't work (other provider):
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fartblog.pa-la.fi%2Ffacebook%2F

As there is dash (-) in other domain's (& server's) name, I was thinking it might be the "dash-bug", but debugger can find info from the root domain, so that doesn't seem to be the problem either. I'd give the link ready here too, but I don't have enough reputation for this system here.

Anyway, server provider's answer is: "I'd suggest you contact facebook's support on this issue, as everything looks ok on our end with the info they provide."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the provider, works now.